# Dell Inspiron 15r won't play sound after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: audio, windows-10

I was really excited to get windows 10 on the first of August but once I installed the update, the sound drivers broke.

This happened right after I installed it- I couldn't call my friend on Skype because their was a audio playback problem.
A day later I went to check YouTube and the same problem happened.

I checked the audio tab and it says my audio device is on, is default and working perfectly.

I tried disabling and re-enabling the machine, and it doesn't solve it.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

## UPDATE

I just happened to go into the drivers folder and took a peek in the audio section.  Only one folder was there, so I opened that one. The folder said "Vista64".

So I have Windows Vista sound drivers on windows 10. Yipee.

Comment: Try to open youtube, start something and then change the volume several times one by one. For me the sound appears in 3-5 seconds. It's not normal. but I currently have no time to search for good solution.

Comment: I wonder if you need to re-install a driver.

Comment: didn't work. I tried re-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably out of luck.  From Dell's website for drivers for the [Inspiron 15r](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15r-5520/drivers):

> Product not tested for Windows 10 upgrade
>
> Dell is not testing or developing Windows 10 drivers for this product. If you choose to upgrade, some features, applications, and connected devices may not work as expected.

However, you *may* be able to get drivers from the sound card manufacturer.

Unfortunately, a lot of people have forcefully upgraded to Windows 10, without thinking to check if their hardware was compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into file manager...

This PC → OS(C) → Drivers → Audio → G68MD → Production → Windows8-64 → Setup

and install, restart and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

what  is the manufacture of the audio device  try searching their support section for help or  be creative and write your own driver and sell it to everyone who fell for windows 10? there is a good chance you may be able to find a driver for another similar device  that is  supported in windows 10 and  edit it on the binary layer to  load the other driver using the signed  package for 10.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This post is really a comment rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).